# Is there a way to see the order in which functions are called when we execute a program in Xcode?

Tags: swift, debugging, method-call

Is there a way to see the order in which functions are called when we execute a program in Xcode? For instance, at runtime, if we press a button corresponding to a certain IBAction, can we see the order of method calls thereafter? I know the debugger is available, but it seems to be particularly useful when you know exactly what method calls you are looking for.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Your methods? Cocoa’s methods? That’s a LOT of methods! What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @matt Hi Matt! Sorry for not being clear. I was referring to my methods. I'm trying to parse some open source code and I would like to see the order certain functions (implemented in the main project, not pods) are executed once the user executes an action.

Comment: Well just insert `print(#function)` as the first line of every method. I know it sounds primitive but I’ve learned a huge amount by doing that.

Comment: “but it seems to be particularly useful when you know exactly what method calls you are looking for.” I cant agree with that. Just keep saying Step Into. Actually you can trace your Callees or the Call Hierarchy without running any code at all. I don’t think you’re appreciating the tools you’ve been given.

Comment: @matt Okay, thanks so much! Might be more like I'm oblivious to them! :)

Comment: @matt Sorry for bothering you again. You mentioned we can trace the callees and the call hierarchy without running any code. Do you mind elaborating how I can do this? Thanks again!

Comment: Well when you do a global search in the Find navigator you can choose Call Hierarchy. It’s brilliant. And if you’re in a method, choose from the first icon in the jump bar and choose Callers or Callees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift flows top to bottom. This is a good post on that. As well you can run a breakpoint, also added an explanation of a breakpoint. You can use them to stop and manually advance Xcode to the next thing to execute helps a lot with debugging.

You could also do `print("Function x")`
in each of the functions you have. This would then print them in order of execution time.

[Swift Flow](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/3s5wmn/how_does_swift_flow_in_what_order_are_functions/)

[Breakpoint Article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)